# Android sdk 31 get notified if call is ended

Tags: java, android, telephony

I have an app that uses the callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL) to make a call. I need a way to get notified when the user ends the call.

I used to use telephonyManager.listen but its been deprecated. I see I am supposed to use registerTelephonyCallback but I cant find out how that works.

Can anyone give me some pointers how to do this

Thanks

Comment: are you making phone call inside your app or you are redirecting user to the phone app ?

Comment: im using the dialer intent

Comment: you can have one boolean variable
for example 
var calling = false
makeCallFunction(){
     calling = true
}

onResume() {
  if(calling){
       // here you get the case when your activity is open after call
   }

}

Answer (score 1):

I solved it as follows

```
public class MyCallStateListener extends TelephonyCallback implements TelephonyCallback.CallStateListener {
    private String TAG = "MyCallStateListener";
    @Override
    public void onCallStateChanged(int state) {
        switch (state) {
            case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE: {
                Log.v(TAG, "&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&& state is CALL_STATE_IDLE");
                break;
            }
            case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK: {
                Log.v(TAG, "&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&& state is CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK");
                break;
            }
            default: {
                Log.v(TAG, "state is " + state);
            }
        }
    }
}

TelephonyManager telephonyManager =
                (TelephonyManager)getContext().getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
        TelephonyCallback telephonyCallback = new MyCallStateListener();
        telephonyManager.registerTelephonyCallback(getContext().getMainExecutor(),  telephonyCallback);
```